# how to get all members id in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

i am trying to a make a list of all the members id of a given guild id. I am trying various things but all are giving collections. how can i only retrieve the ids.

```
console.log(msg.guild.name)
console.log(msg.guild.id)
console.log(msg.guild.members.fetch());
```

the log is

```
 '690958932406960249' => GuildMember {
 guild: [Guild],
 user: [User],
 joinedTimestamp: 1586525303612,
 lastMessageID: null,
 lastMessageChannelID: null,
 premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
 deleted: false,
 _roles: []
 },
'690988332653608980' => GuildMember {
guild: [Guild],
user: [User],
joinedTimestamp: 1591198472051,
lastMessageID: null,
lastMessageChannelID: null,
premiumSinceTimestamp: null,
deleted: false,
 _roles: []
 },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the members' IDs using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
Example:

```js
const Members = client.guilds.cache.get("GuildID").members.map(member => member.id);
// Returns Array: ["4634643643262345", "684369346943609235", "4683496834643653543"] etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the collection, you can use `.keys()` method to get the keys (ID of the members).

```
let memberIds = Array.from(collection.keys())
```